# HTML form - limit to X saves per hour per IP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, I need to receive data (just one string from a form, it's a name what it receives):

```
$received_data = $_POST['data'];
$ip = checkip();
```

And the 'user' IP (it not needs cookies or session and I can't use them), I must to save both datas (data and ip) on a database and allow to see 5 per hour, but allow to see the same that already saw, I mean the 'data' stored on database can see without limit, but only 5 differents datas (names) per hour, for example:

Can check: Martha, Jack, Lily, Mark and Peter (per hour, and the next hour can check others or maybe the same - depens on user).

And in the same hour can check the five names already checked, but not other til the next hour.

And if try to check Martha, Jack and then Martha again, (the second Martha) not counts, because it's already checked in the same hour.

I don't know how can I do it, could anybody help me?

Thank you in advanced, kind regards.

Comment: I understand you don't know how to do this, but would you let us know what you found when you researched this question via web searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

function maxSavePerHour($data, $ip, $maxSave = 5){

    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

    // Get record matching within last hour
    $res = mysql_query("select * from table where data='$data' and ip='$ip' and lastinsert <= date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour)";

     $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($res);

    // If a record was NOT found within last hour matching everything then insert new record.

      // Compare records against max saves
      if($totalRows <= $maxSave){
        $storeData = true;
      }else{
        $storeData = false;
      }  


   if($storeData){
      $res = mysql_query("insert into table set data='$data', ip='$ip'";
      //Add more exception handling here....
    }

}


$ip = getRealIpAddr();
$data = $_POST['data'];

maxSavePerHour($data,$ip);
```

Comment: very bad: http_x_forwarded_for can be easily manipulated by the client.

Comment: @develroot Please write a better option for the poster. I prefer constructive criticism but suggestions of very bad don't do us any good.

Comment: i can set the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header to be '127.0.0.1' and the getRealIpAddr() function will return 127.0.0.1, which is not my real ip address.

Comment: That may be true but we only have so much control over the client side. Like I said develop a better solution if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a rethink with respect to using IP addresses. Many organisations/ISP have many computers to share an IP address.

As to verifying only 5 per hour you need to store the time stamps of the last 5 items of data received. If fewer that five then everything is OK.

Otherwise check the time of the eldest. If over 1 hour then OK and update the database by deleting the oldest time stamp and replacing it with a new one. Otherwise it should fail.